# How can i use the headers in the main project in a subproject?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a header name "Header.h" in project A and i try to import it in sub-project B by using the standard

```
#import "Header.h"
```

The thing is that although auto-complete finds my header and though my header is used in other places with success, i get an error telling me that the header couldn't be found.

How can i include in a subproject the headers from the main project without having to copy all the headers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a little bit weird to use main project's .h file in a sub-project. It will cause the two projects can NOT be separated any more. That's not the project / sub-project struct designed for.

So, why don't you just move all of those classes from your main project into your sub-project if so you can still use them from your main project?

Anyway, if you insist on keeping those classes in your main project, have you tried to add those .h files into your sub-project? You do NOT need to copy them into your sub-project, just add them as references should be OK.

Comment: i've tried to add the .h files but they are not recognized (although, again, the auto-complete finds them)

Comment: The auto-complete is the ability of Xcode, which will find every thing in your project and frameworks you've included. But when you compile your code, it's the compiler to find them, if the compiler can't, you will get a compile error. I am thinking if this will really work, since the sub-project is always compiled before your main-project, how could it be able to use some thing not compiled yet? I am not sure, but maybe you do need to remove all of these ".h" **AND** ".m" files into your sub-project...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's in your app's folder? If not, you have to add it's parent-directory to the `Header Search Paths`-variable in your `Target Settings`.

Comment: if it works in other files and it won't work only in this folder then i presume it is in the app's folder.. it is found by auto-complete dus it is in the app's folder

Comment: Okay, I forgot about that. Let's look at it in another angle: is your main-file in the same dir as your other main-files?

Comment: the sub-project("Three20") is located in the root of my main project.

Comment: Okay, it's weird it works in other places, since you really need to add its path to `Header Search Paths` in this situation. What happens when you use my answer?